# Measure distance to coast along river

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, distance, rivers

I have a dataset on rivers and a dataset on the location of dams. I want to calculate the distance from the dams to the river’s mouth at the coast along the river (not the shortest distance) for those dams located next to one of the rivers in the dataset. 
These are the datasets:

```
var rivers = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines_scale_rank');
var coast = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/GSHHS_i_L1');
var grand_dams = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/GRanD_dams_v1_3');
```

I guess the spatial join of the rivers and dams looks something like this:

```
// Define a spatial filter, with distance of 2 km.
var distFilter = ee.Filter.withinDistance({
  distance: 2000,
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
});

var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'scenes',
});

var dam_river= saveAllJoin.apply(grand_dams, rivers, distFilter);
```

I don’t know where to start to solve the problem.

Comment: I am getting an error `Collection asset 'users/basins/ne_10m_rivers_lake_centerlines_scale_rank' not found.` Can you please confirm that the asset path is correct and/or make the asset public?

Comment: Sorry. I thought I shared it. It should be accessible now.

Comment: No problem! I am able to load the featureCollection now. Looking into a couple options to implement the problem....it is an interesting one!

Comment: Did you find any solution?